# Read lines of file in C

Tags: c, file, input, readline

I am trying to read line by line a standard file input.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1204

char* readLine(char* buffer){
    int i = 0;
    for(i; i< BUFFER_SIZE; i++){
        printf("%c",buffer[i]);
        if( '\n' == buffer[i]){
            char* line[124];
            memcpy( line, &buffer[0], i-1 );
            return *line;
        }
    }
    free(buffer);
}
int doStuffWithLine(char* line){
    return 1;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ssize_t aux1;
    char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFFER_SIZE);
    char *line = malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFFER_SIZE);
    while((read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE))>0){ 
        line = readLine(buffer);
        doStuffWithLine(line);
        printf("%s", line);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the input file content:

```
lol1
lol2
lol3
```

And this is the output of my program:

```
lol1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I want to know how read lines 2 and 3, solve it and a little explanation about what I am doing wrong because I do not understand the problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Rather than `char* line[124];` in function `readLine()`, an array of pointers, I suspect you meant `char line[124];` however since this is a local variable, you can't return it's address and expect to be able to access it. You need to create a second buffer in your `main()` as large as `BUFFER_SIZE ` and add that buffer to your argument list for `readline()` so that the buffer will exist when you call the function `doStuffWithLine()` and will be large enugh.

Comment: You're freeing `buffer` at the end of `readLine`

Comment: In `readline()` you `free(buffer)`, but in the next iteration You use the buffer again as if it was still allocated.

Comment: You're not adding the NUL termination to the end of `buffer` when you've `read()` the text in. You need to track the return value from `read` to know how much is read into `buffer`

Comment: `char* line[124]` is declared local to `readLine` and its storage becomes invalid on return. Either allocate storage within `readLine` and return a pointer to the allocated block, or pass an additional parameter providing the required storage for `line`.

Comment: Deconstructing the `readLine()` function is hard.  It does a lot of very odd things.  On the whole, you need to specify exactly what the function is supposed to do and then reimplement it to do that.  You seem to have a very mixed bag of activities in there, and all hell will break loose on the second iteration of the loop in `main()` if the input is big enough.  Using the length `1204` is unusual — but not technically wrong; it looks like a typo for `1024`, though.

Comment: Note that `readline()` is a C library function, exposed by the header file: `stdio.h`  So the posted code will result in a mismatch between the library function and what you have written.  Suggest giving your function a unique name, like: `myReadLine()`\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thank you all that helped me and spent some time trying it.

After spending some hours learning and breaking my brain I have found a solution. In conclusion I am ***** and noob.

If someone is having the same problem I am submitting my code. Easy peasy:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>

char* doStuff(char* line){
    return line;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *line = malloc(sizeof(char)*LINE_MAX);
    while(fgets(line, LINE_MAX, stdin)!= NULL)
    {
        line = doStuff(line);
        printf("%s", line);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: regarding the expression: `sizeof(char)`  The C standard defines that expression to always be 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  It just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest removing that expression

Answer (score 1):

Function `read` reads in raw bytes and will not terminate your buffer with a string termination character `'\0'`; Using it then for `printf("%s",...)`, which expects a `0`-terminated C-string, yields undefined behaviour (e.g. a crash).

I'd suggest to use `fgets` instead.